# How to convert from RGB555 to RGB888 in c#?

Tags: c#, rgb

I need to convert 16-bit XRGB1555 into 24-bit RGB888. My function for this is below, but it's not perfect, i.e. a value of 0b11111 wil give 248 as the pixel value, not 255. This function is for little-endian, but can easily be modified for big-endian.

```
public static Color XRGB1555(byte b0, byte b1)
{ 
    return Color.FromArgb(0xFF, (b1 & 0x7C) << 1, ((b1 & 0x03) << 6) | ((b0 & 0xE0) >> 2), (b0 & 0x1F) << 3); 
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would normally copy the highest bits down to the bottom bits, so if you had five bits as follows:

```
Bit position: 4 3 2 1 0
Bit variable: A B C D E
```

You would extend that to eight bits as:

```
Bit position: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Bit variable: A B C D E A B C
```

That way, all zeros remains all zeros, all ones becomes all ones, and values in between scale appropriately.

(Note that A,B,C etc aren't supposed to be hex digits - they are variables representing a single bit).

Comment: so if x is the result of my current function, I want x|(x>>5)

Comment: Yep that's correct assuming your value is in bits 7-3, or as @CodeInChaos specifies, if you have it in bits 4-0, then it's (x<<3)|(x>>2).

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a lookup table. Since there are only 32 different values it even fits in a cache-line.

You can get the 8 bit value from the 5 bit value with:
`return (x<<3)||(x>>2);`

The rounding might not be perfect though. I.e. the result isn't always closest to the input, but it never is further away that 1/255.

Comment: Re the rounding, you end up being 1/255 too low for 3/31 and 7/31, and 1/255 too high for 24/31 and 28/31.